# Chrome - inputs align in a div (works on FF & IE)

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, alignment

On the main page of [my website](http://www.vivremieuxchaquejour.fr/)  I have a problem concerning the two inputs located at the top right of the page ("Rechercher" text field and "OK" button).
In fact, my CSS works on FF & IE but not on Chrome.
To make it more generic, it's just two input in a div.
Can you help me to correct this misbehaviour on Chrome?

Thanks a lot guys!

**CSS of the "Rechercher" text field:**

```
 #champ_recherche_style {
height:14px;
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-top:15px;
width:150px;
}
```

**CSS of the "OK" button:**

```
 #habillage_bouton_texte_recherche_style {
background-color:#8C8C8C;
color:#FFFFFF;
display:inline;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
margin:15px 1px 0 10px;
padding:0 3px;
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

**CSS of the div:**

```
 #encart_recherche_style {
padding-left:746px;
text-align:center;
width:210px;
}
```

Comment: I can't make it work.. The fact is that the template is very bad but I just have the possibility to modify the CSS.

Nobody can find why the button "OK" is not on the same line? One object must be creating this mess :'(

Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

In general, tables are terrible for layout, but if you MUST use them, just put your button in a TD after the input's TD instead of putting the input field in a table by itself and attempting to force the table to display inline.

I highly suggest learning how to use CSS for your layouts in the future.

Again, I don't recommend tables for layout, but...

**Instead of:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> INPUT IS HERE </td>
    </tr>
</table>
BUTTON IS HERE
```

**Try this:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> INPUT GOES HERE </td>
        <td> BUTTON GOES HERE </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I will be pleased to change the html code, which, I agree with u, is horrible. Unfortunatly, we use a proprietary CMS and we just have access to the CSS.. not the htlm :(

Answer (score 0):

Using inline-block instead of inline on your table will get you closer to the behavior you want.